# Using multiple font colors for multiple integer values conditionally in one cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I am looking to write a VBA program that allows to color sort multiple integer values in one single cell in excel. For example, if numbers less than 10 will be red, for numbers in between 10-20 will be green, and numbers greater than 20 will be yellow. But, two integer values may be placed in one cell so it is possible that two numbers have different colors inside that cell. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the **numbers text font to be colored**, or to the **cell Interior**? For cell interior you should use Conditional Formatting, but Excel does not allow more than a color for the cell Interior, and two numbers does not have any meaning in such a case. Then, if you try talking about numbers font color, how will they be separated in the same cell?

Comment: You might want to screenshot an example of the data you have - and how you'd like it formatted.

Comment: @FaneDuru, am referring to the numbers text font to be colored.

Comment: @CLR for example, in the cell text is "4 (12)" where 4 will be red and 12 will be green. The parenthesis will remain black though.

Comment: Is this an example of the pattern which will always be the same? I mean, the second number between parenthesis? Can they also be differently separated? "4, 12", "4 12", "4,12" etc.? Nothing can be done for a general 'example' not always respecting the same pattern...

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes this will be the pattern. The second number will always be between a parenthesis and they cannot be differently separated.

Comment: Which to be the maximum number of digits for both numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not answer my last clarification question... The above solution assumes that the maximum number of digits for each numbers (they may be more then two) is **3**. The numbers must be separated with any separator. The patern involving the second number between parenthesis is also covered. It also assumes that the range to be processed in **in "A:A" column**. The code can be easily adapted to work on any column:

```
Sub ColorNubersFontConditionaly()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, strVal As String, necCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, nbPos As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary worksheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last filled cell in column A:A
   For i = 2 To lastR 'iterate between the range cells
        nbPos = 1: strVal = sh.Range("A" & i).Value 'place the cell value in a string
        arr = extrAllNumb(strVal)     'the array of extracted numbers
        If IsArray(arr) Then         
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr)  'process each extracted  number and color it according the mentioned conditions
                nbPos = InStr(nbPos, strVal, arr(j), vbTextCompare)
                If CLng(arr(j)) < 10 Then
                    necCol = vbRed
                ElseIf CLng(arr(j)) >= 10 And CLng(arr(j)) <= 20 Then
                    necCol = vbGreen
                Else
                    necCol = vbYellow
                End If
                sh.Range("A" & i).Characters(nbPos, Len(arr(j))).Font.Color = necCol
                nbPos = nbPos + Len(arr(j))
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
End Sub

Private Function extrAllNumb(strVal As String) As Variant 'it return an array containing all numbers having between 1 and 3 digits
    Dim Res As Object, El, arr, i As Long
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d{1,3})"
        .Global = True
        If .test(strVal) Then
            Set Res = .Execute(strVal)
            ReDim arr(Res.count - 1)
            For Each El In Res
                arr(i) = El: i = i + 1
            Next
        End If
    End With
    extrAllNumb = arr
End Function
```

Please, send some feedback after testing the code.

**Edited**:

```
Sub ColorNubersFontConditionalyTwoCond()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, strVal As String, necCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, nbPos As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary worksheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last filled cell in column A:A
   For i = 2 To lastR
        nbPos = 1: strVal = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        arr = extrAllNumb(strVal)
        If IsArray(arr) Then
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                nbPos = InStr(nbPos, strVal, arr(j), vbTextCompare)
                If j = 0 Then
                    If CLng(arr(j)) < 10 Then
                        necCol = vbRed
                    ElseIf CLng(arr(j)) >= 10 And CLng(arr(j)) <= 20 Then
                        necCol = vbGreen
                    Else
                        necCol = vbYellow
                    End If
                Else
                    'place the new conditions:
                     If CLng(arr(j)) < 5 Then 'use here your necessary limit conditions...
                        necCol = vbRed
                    ElseIf CLng(arr(j)) >= 5 And CLng(arr(j)) <= 25 Then
                        necCol = vbGreen
                    Else
                        necCol = vbYellow
                    End If
                End If
                sh.Range("A" & i).Characters(nbPos, Len(arr(j))).Font.Color = necCol
                nbPos = nbPos + Len(arr(j))
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Of course, the new version will use the same `extrAllNumb`, too...

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. But may I ask if there is a way if for the second number that's inside the parenthesis, its condition is different from the first number outside the parenthesis? Thanks.

Comment: @nics12 If the number inside the parenthesis is **always the second one** it is easy to do it, in terms of code conditions setting. But you should explain what those "different" does mean...

Comment: Yes, the number inside the parenthesis is always the second one. The different means that the conditions for it being green, red, yellow, are different values than the first.

Comment: how can I add another conditions setting for the second number thats inside the parenthesis? Thanks.

Comment: @nics12 OK. I will edit my question and add a new example version to deal in the way (I understood) you need.

Comment: Okay, the code works perfectly. Thanks a lot @FaneDuru!